# How to configure KRFB so that it runs at startup in Kubuntu 15.10 x64?

Tags: vnc, kubuntu

How to configure KRFB so that it runs at startup in Kubuntu 15.10 x64?

(Krfb Desktop Sharing [is](https://www.kde.org/applications/system/krfb/) a server application that allows you to share your current session with a user on another machine, who can use a VNC client to view or even control the desktop.)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add it in `Autostart section` of `Startup and Shutdown`

[image]

[image]

[image]